# Error: ansible requires a json module, none found

Tags: json, ansible

Error while executing ansible ping module

```
bash ~ ansible webservers  -i inventory -m ping  -k  -u root -vvvv
SSH password: 
<~> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: root on PORT 22 TO ~
<my-lnx> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: root on PORT 22 TO my-lnx
~ | FAILED => FAILED: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
<my-lnx> REMOTE_MODULE ping
<my-lnx> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1423302966.66-77716810353582 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1423302966.66-77716810353582'
<my-lnx> PUT /var/folders/8n/fftvnbbs51q834y16vfvb1q00000gn/T/tmpP6zwZj TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1423302966.66-77716810353582/ping
<my-lnx> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1423302966.66-77716810353582/ping; rm -rf /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1423302966.66-77716810353582/ >/dev/null 2>&1'
my-lnx | FAILED >> {
    "failed": true, 
    "msg": "Error: ansible requires a json module, none found!", 
    "parsed": false
}
```

This is my inventory file

```
bash ~ cat inventory 
[webservers]
my-lnx  ansible_ssh_host=my-lnx ansible_ssh_port=22
```

I have installed simplejosn module also in the client as well as remote machine

```
bash ~ pip list | grep json
simple-json (1.1)
simplejson (3.6.5)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible + 10.11.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799807/ansible-10-11-6)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you need to install the `python-simplejson` module.

Try to run this command first and then your desired commands:

```
 ansible webservers -i inventory -m raw -a "sudo yum install -y python-simplejson"  -k  -u root -vvvv
```

I am supposing that its old Red Hat/CentOS system.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want or can't install the python-simplejson module on remote servers, you can simply request the raw output instead:

```
> ansible webservers -i inventory -m ping -m raw
```

Or like I did, added it to my ~/.bash_profile

```
alias ansible="ansible -m raw"

# And then simply running:
> ansible webservers -i inventory -m ping
```

Answer (score 1):

in centos 5.* version no python-simple json available on repo to donwload and install. you can simple use below mentioned method.

make sure both the source and destination should be accessed password less and from source to destination also password less.

use ssh-keygen -t rsa to generate key
ssh-copy-id user@host_ip

"---
 - hosts: (ansible host)
   become: yes
   remote_user: root
   gather_facts: false
   tasks:
     - name: copying copying temps
       shell: ssh (source) && rsync -parv /root/temp/* root@(Destination):/root/temp/"