# Ansible + 10.11.6

Tags: python, macos, ansible

I'm having a weird issue with Ansible on a (very) clean install of 10.11.6. I've installed brew, zsh, oh-my-zsh, Lil' snitch and 1password (and literally nothing else). I installed ansible with...

`brew install ansible`

... which was successful. I then went to a preexisting (and crazy simple) Ansible project and did an...

`ansible -m ping all`

It then asked me to enter my SSH passphrase. I've reinstated the keys from my previous install but I hadn't previously ssh'd into the server. I entered the passphrase and ansible returned...

```
$ ansible -m ping all               
host1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
"changed": false, 
"msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", 
"unreachable": true
}
```

I then ssh'd into the server to check all was well, and it connected without any problems.

I then re-ran...

`$ ansible -m ping all`

and it returned...

```
host1 | FAILED! => {
"changed": false, 
"failed": true, 
"module_stderr": "", 
"module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found\r\n", 
"msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
"parsed": false
}
```

... which is a bit weird? It seems to be saying it can't find python anymore, despite it finding it first time around?

`$ which python` returns `/usr/bin/python`

`$ python --version` returns `Python 2.7.10`

`$ which ansible` returns `/usr/local/bin/ansible`

`$ ansible --version` returns

```
ansible 2.1.1.0
config file = /pathtoproject/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

I've deliberately not installed pyenv, virtualenv etc.

`/usr/bin/python` is definitely there, and I can run python without any problems.

Help?! :-) I'm a Ruby dev and I can't help but think I'm missing something obvious, but as I understand it all the versions check out and everything *should* be working. I tried changing my shell to sh and rerunning `ansible -m ping all` but it fails in the same way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Annnnnnnd, as it turns out, ansible needs python installed on the host. 

Who knew? Not me. ;-)

Sorted!

Answer (score 5):

This happens if there is no python installed on the remote hosts.
The [ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#managed-node-requirements)  suggests doing this for every host by hand: `ansible myhost --sudo -m raw -a "yum install -y python2 python-simplejson"`

However I think it's nicer to bootstrap all of your hosts with this snippet at the start of you playbook:

`- name: Bootrstrap python
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    raw: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y python-simplejson
    delegate_to: '{{ item }}'
    with_items: {{ groups["hosts"] }}`

Comment: equivalent with apt would be `ansible myhost --sudo -m raw -a "apt-get install -y python2.7 python-simplejson"`

Comment: to use a specific hosts file named `hosts` and specify the group you want, use `ansible -i hosts group-name -m raw  -a "apt-get install -y python2.7 python-simplejson"`

Comment: This fixed for me, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but the "fix" was stranger yet: remove Python3 from the host, as Ansible currently supports up to Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Python3 don't work with Ansible (....

1. `apt-get install -y python2.7 python-simplejson` on remote server. Not necessary remove any other versions.
2. your permission to `id_rsa` must be only 'read' - `chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` - either you can get another error "UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!"